# Count non blank values by category

Tags: excel

I would like to count of occurences where cells aren't blank for each category (placed in rows)

**Sample Data set:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

I would like the formula inside the column col to reflect whatever value is on the left in the color col. In other words if I change blue to orange, the count should update as well.

Comment: Did you try using `COUNTA`?

Comment: Or COUNTIF() or SUMPRODUCT(), there are many ways, what have you tried?

Comment: They are fine, but its not dynamic. in other words, if i  change the blue for something else the function using counta, countif, wont take that the update into account

Comment: Like I know I could simply do a COUNTA for the row of blue and orange and green. but its not dynamic. If I replace the green and orange it won't work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$D$4<>"")*($A$2:$A$4=H2))
```

[image]

COUNTIF()(only if they are truly null):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),"<>")
```

COUNTA(same as COUNTIF, Has to be null)

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$4,0),0))
```

Or COUNT(if they are all numbers like your example:

```
=COUNT(INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$4,0))
```

With Office 365 the INDEX/MATCH in the bottom 2 can be replaced with FILTER(COUNTIF requires a range not an array:

```
FILTER($B$2:$D$4,$A$2:$A$4=H2)
```

Comment: insanely efficient and quick thanks

Comment: every 4 seconds, theres a new edit with anew answer, im literally in awe...